# Which method to calculate distance from coordinates

Tags: python, coordinate-system, openlayers, distance

I have a project to know the distance between two points (Long, Lat).
The web app uses **openlayers** (CRS from 4326 to 900913).
I have written a jupyter notebook to check the distance in python.

https://nbviewer.org/github/Webismagic/GIS/blob/862ea9487aadb44d1f39689351a086d9d1454b99/bsp.ipynb

The problem is that I have differences between methods.

The points (Long,Lat): (-17.314608 , 28.067808), (-17.32907, 28.04381) (La Gomera, Canary islands)

First method using **Geopy** package.

Distance: 3015.660773645268 m

Second method using **Shapely** with different **CRS**

crs 4326 to 4083 : 3016.3930360833283 m (UTM of Canary islands)

crs 4326 to 5634 : 3125.312697809095 m

crs 4326 to 900913 : 3428.6341730737054 m (Google maps)

I think that I need to replace the CRS of the web app : 900913 to 4083.
Is that correct?

Comment: Using OL `ol.sphere.getDistance` method gives 3022 meters. This is the great circle distance between the points.

Comment: turf.js method `turf.distance` gives exactly the same result: 3022 meters.

Answer (score 2):

When you reproject to a projected coordinate system, the distance method is probably using a planar calculation. 5634, for instance, uses Lambert conformal conic and is centered in Europe so more distance distortion than the UTM zone. UTM isn't distance-preserving either and 3857/900913 is notoriously bad at distances. Look for a geodesic or in a pinch a great circle method like @TomazicM suggested; then the CRS doesn't matter.